# Retrieving the First Instance of a Character Preceding a Specified Index

Tags: r, string, text-processing

I want to retrieve a word preceding a specified key word in R. For example, if I pass in:

`The Red Dog`

and "Dog" is the specified keyword, I want to be able to retrieve the word "Red" and save it to a vector. Is there a function that can do this that already exists? I have looked through the stringr package with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
prior_word <- function(x, w, if_first = "[The First Word]"){
    xs = strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
    c(if_first, xs)[ match(w, xs) ]
}
```

Examples:

```
prior_word("The Red Red Dog", "Red")
# "The"
```

So only the first instance of "Red" is recognized.

```
prior_word("The Red Dog", c("The","Red","Dog", "Pirate"))
# "[The First Word]" "The"              "Red"              NA
```

If a word is first, some default value is returned; and if the word is not found, `NA`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would there be a way to edit this function to make the input an index of a character, and it would retrieve the preceding word?

Comment: If the "index" means its position in the sequence of words, then something like `prior_word2 <- function(x, wpos, if_first = "[The First Word]") c(if_first, strsplit(x, " ")[[1]])[ wpos ]` for example `prior_word2(x,2)` gives the first word of `x`.

Comment: So helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing. What if I wanted to pass in the index of a character in a string? like if "The Red Dog" was the string, I passed 4 as the index parameter to the string (index of "R" in the above string) and I wanted to retrieve "The"?

Comment: Hm, I think that's tougher to extend from this approach...`cumsum` and `nchar` might help. Maybe you should post it as a new question.